# Get recurrences from a list in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I have the following list

```
[['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['gvt', 1], ['tools', 2], ['drm', 14], ['vgem', 12], ['template', 2], ['gem', 101], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['kms', 7], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['meta', 8], ['drv', 24], ['gen3', 5], ['sw', 18], ['syncobj', 81], ['gen7', 1], ['testdisplay', 1], ['debugfs', 3], ['perf', 27], ['core', 17], ['prime', 134]]
```

and I am trying to get recurrences, e.g :

from this part of the list

```
['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15]
```

I want to get the following :

pm found 4 times, with 4 values of 15

Another example :

```
['kms', 7], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150]
```

kms found 10 times, with 9 values of 150 and 1 value of 7

So far, I am wondering how can I do this?

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: i've iterate over the list, but i am not have the enough logical to perform this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a combo of Counter and defaultdict

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

l = [['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['gvt', 1], ['tools', 2], ['drm', 14], ['vgem', 12], ['template', 2], ['gem', 101], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['kms', 7], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['meta', 8], ['drv', 24], ['gen3', 5], ['sw', 18], ['syncobj', 81], ['gen7', 1], ['testdisplay', 1], ['debugfs', 3], ['perf', 27], ['core', 17], ['prime', 134]]

# Get counts by converting lists to tuples
d = Counter((tuple(i) for i in l))

# Create an empty defaultdict with dict
final_d = defaultdict(dict)

# Fill the dict with values from tuples
for k, v in d.items():
    final_d[k[0]][k[1]] = v

final_d.keys()
```

Returns a dictionary with these keys:

```
dict_keys(['perf', 'pm', 'gen3', 'testdisplay', 'drv', 'syncobj', 'drm', 'gen7', 'gvt', 'template', 'gem', 'vgem', 'tools', 'kms', 'core', 'prime', 'sw', 'meta', 'debugfs'])
```

Now you can get the occurences with:

```
final_d.get('pm')
final_d.get('kms')
```

Returns:

```
{15: 4} #pm
{7: 1, 150: 9} #kms
```

---

**Update**

Another solution would be to use a nested defaultdict from the start:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = [['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['gvt', 1], ['tools', 2], ['drm', 14], ['vgem', 12], ['template', 2], ['gem', 101], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['kms', 7], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['meta', 8], ['drv', 24], ['gen3', 5], ['sw', 18], ['syncobj', 81], ['gen7', 1], ['testdisplay', 1], ['debugfs', 3], ['perf', 27], ['core', 17], ['prime', 134]]

# Create an empty defaultdict with dict
final_d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))

# Fill the dict with values from tuples
for item in l:
    final_d[item[0]][item[1]] += 1
```

Comment: @shaveax No worries, also have a look at my updated solution which uses a nested defaultdict which result in a compact code.

Comment: sure, i will take a look ;)

Answer (score 2):

If converting those records to tuples isn't a problem to you, you can use `Counter` to solve your problem.

Example solution

```
from collections import Counter

tuples = tuple(tuple(item) for item in items) # where items is your data
c = Counter(tuples)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what i am looking for, thanks a lot Progress1ve ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` and `collections.Counter`:

```
import itertools
from collections import Counter
s = [['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['pm', 15], ['gvt', 1], ['tools', 2], ['drm', 14], ['vgem', 12], ['template', 2], ['gem', 101], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['gem', 150], ['kms', 7], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['kms', 150], ['meta', 8], ['drv', 24], ['gen3', 5], ['sw', 18], ['syncobj', 81], ['gen7', 1], ['testdisplay', 1], ['debugfs', 3], ['perf', 27], ['core', 17], ['prime', 134]]
new_s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(s, key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])]
for a, b in new_s:
   print("{} found {} times, with {}".format(a, len(b), ' '.join('{} values of {}'.format(d, c) for c, d in Counter([i[-1] for i in b]).items())))
```

Output:

```
core found 1 times, with 1 values of 17
debugfs found 1 times, with 1 values of 3
drm found 1 times, with 1 values of 14
drv found 1 times, with 1 values of 24
gem found 16 times, with 1 values of 101 15 values of 150
gen3 found 1 times, with 1 values of 5
gen7 found 1 times, with 1 values of 1
gvt found 1 times, with 1 values of 1
kms found 10 times, with 9 values of 150 1 values of 7
meta found 1 times, with 1 values of 8
perf found 1 times, with 1 values of 27
pm found 4 times, with 4 values of 15
prime found 1 times, with 1 values of 134
sw found 1 times, with 1 values of 18
syncobj found 1 times, with 1 values of 81
template found 1 times, with 1 values of 2
testdisplay found 1 times, with 1 values of 1
tools found 1 times, with 1 values of 2
vgem found 1 times, with 1 values of 12
```

The output grammar is somewhat generic, but I believe you can round it out.